# Get all UI locators from Android/iOS screen for Mobile Automation Testing

Tags: appium, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, ddms, ddmlib

Problem Definition: I am trying to develop a Utility which can mirror an Android/iOS device screen in my windows and on a button click it provides all the locators available on the screen in one xls file.

I am trying to find a direction to work on this. Till now i am able find that using ddmlib library for Android we can interact with DDMS. I do not know how to interact with this ddmlib library. Plus is it possible to mirror Android Screen using the ddmlib library? still a question to me.

On iOS front no luck.

Looking for a direction. Thanks!

Comment: First to print the pagesource can u try this,

System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
 and save it to a file...does this address the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the developer to set the same ids of Android to iOS UI views

they just have to set the **Accessibility Identifier** to each element would solve the issue.

they can do it in Interface builder or programatically

```
view.AccessibilityIdentifier = "CreditCardTextField";
```

or else you have to find xpath for each element and do it which is harder

Answer (score 0):

You can just inspect elements for both android and ios usiing appium inspector..

There is a **Copy XML** button in appium inspector which will save all locators as a xml file on single button click

Comment: XML doesn't contain all objects, it contains only app_view elements, if in case, app is using any webview then you element inspector -- may be get the whole page source and then apply your logic there.

Comment: @Sunder Thank you for the response but i am looking to find a way to do the same customarily.

Comment: @Pankaj How to do it for Native apps?

Comment: @pankaj this appium inspector will capture all uia element object of iOS/Android even for both native and hybrid app in native context..than any other tool can..for webview context you can use normal dom elements to automate using appium